# How do you dynamically add side panel menu items with jQuery Mobile and keep all CSS styling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I pulled very small snippets from my code to show a very simple example of my problem.  I put it in JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/hollycoffee/LjLMU/

I have researched and found others with the same issue and they either tried *addClass* or *refresh* jQuery methods, so I tried both in a few different places in my code and nothing worked, so I'm hoping that by making the simple example in JSFiddle, someone can point me to exactly what I am missing and where.

The example is random and won't make sense, but the part that I am stuck on is the fact that only the dynamic portion of the menu loses style, the Skills list.

The menu portion markup looks like this:

```
<header data-role="header" data-position="absolute" data-theme="a">
    <h1>View Skills</h1>
    <a href="#left-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false">Menu</a>
</header>

<!-- Starting our left side menu panel -->
<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-theme="a">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
        <li data-icon="back"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Back Home</a></li>
    </ul><br />

    <div class="ui-header ui-bar-a" data-theme="a">Settings</div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
        <h3>Optimization Settings</h3>
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#" data-rel="close">Colors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-rel="close">Preferences</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /collapsible-set -->
    </div><!-- /collapsible -->

    <div class="ui-header ui-bar-a" data-theme="a">Skills Menu</div>
    <div id="skillsList"></div>

    <div class="ui-header ui-bar-a" data-theme="a">Saved</div>    
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
        <h3>Saved Searches</h3>
        <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#" data-rel="close">Angry Birds</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-rel="close">Professional Events</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /collapsible-set -->
    </div><!-- /collapsible -->
</div><!-- / Menu panel -->
```

Everything looks good except for the skillsDiv, which is filled by this javascript:

```
function CreateSkillsList(skills){
    var skillsDiv = $('#skillsList');
    var html = "<div data-content-theme=\"a\" data-theme=\"a\" data-iconpos=\"right\"    data-inset=\"false\" data-role=\"collapsible\"><h3>Skills</h3><div data-role=\"collapsible-set\" data-inset=\"false\" data-iconpos=\"right\" data-theme=\"a\" data-content-theme=\"a\">";
    html += "<ul data-role='listview'>";

    var size = skills.length;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        html += "<li><a href=\"#\" data-rel=\"close\"><div id='Skill" + i + "'></div>   </a></li>";
    }

    html += "</ul></div></div>";
    skillsDiv.html(html);     
}
```

Each skill does show as a list item, but has no CSS.

Here is the JSFiddle so you can use the top left Menu button to see the skills list with no style:

http://jsfiddle.net/hollycoffee/LjLMU/

Thank you so much for the help, you StackOverflow geniuses help me every time!
-Holly

(Quick note update - In my real application, I don't use the `$(document).ready()` - I just put it into this example to fill my array for me. My real application gets the array filled by an external API, so I thought this was the simplest way to re-create it.)

Comment: I have updated my answer and the demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Edit:** Add this at the end of your function

```
$('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');
```

---

<strike>Just add `$('[data-role=panel]').trigger('updatelayout');` after injecting items dynamically to panel.</strike>

> [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/z3mws/)

Comment: I tried your demo but it didn't work, it gave me an error that looked like this:   

uncaught exception: Error in Actionscript. Use a try/catch block to find error.
[Break On This Error]  

...e{K=x.u.path}var A=M.path;if(K!=A){if(/\//.test(x.o)){return false}var L=K.split...



What browser did your demo work in?  I am using Firefox.

Comment: I tried it on my iPhone in Safari and the Skills don't populate at all with your demo link.  I'm not sure what's wrong.  Thank you for trying to help me though, Omar.  I really appreciate it! -Holly

Comment: I think it was just missing the top because you removed the .ready line and left a trailing }); at the end.... but when I removed that it still didn't work.  I'm still stumped.

Comment: In my real application, I don't use the .ready.  I just put it into this example to fill my array for me.  My real application gets the array filled by an external API, so this was the simplest way to re-create it....

Comment: I tried adding ('<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-theme="a">').trigger('refresh');
and ('#left-panel').trigger('refresh');
and ('<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-theme="a">').trigger('updatelayout');
and ('#left-panel').trigger('updatelayout');

in the CreateSkillsMenu function before the last close brace.
Nothing is working for me...

Comment: did you only add those 4 lines at the end?

It works now!!  It looks to me like you removed the .ready and added the 4 lines at the bottom.  If you had to do anything additional that I'm not catching please let me know!  

Thank you soooo very much!

Comment: In fact only this `$('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!  Trying to get over this learning curve with jquery mobile.  I appreciate your help so much!

Comment: @codesforcoffee you're welcome :) *trial and error*, good luck.

Comment: Now my actual project menu is working!  I love you, Omar!!!!  I'll be eternally grateful. :D

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('#panel-id').html(yourHtmlHere);
$('#panel-id').trigger('create');
$('#panel-id').trigger('updatelayout');
```

Standard CSS for styling.