# trouble styling dynamically created jquery mobile listview

Tags: jquery, ajax, list, listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to generate a jQuery mobile listview on the fly by pulling down movie data from TMDb and constructing each `<li>` and appending it to an already existing `<ul>` element. trouble is, is that I can't get it for format properly no matter what i do. I'm getting the data and everything from TMDb just fine but the list view isn't styling itself when i call `$("#ul").listview("refresh");`  here is some of my code ( the relevant stuff):

`AJAX CALL THAT GRABS DATA AND BUILDS EACH <li>:`

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action: 'searchFilm',
            film: film
        },
        dataType: "json",
        url: "./php/functions.php",
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json);
            for(var i = 0;  i < Object.size(json); i++){
                var film = json[i.toString()];
                $('#film-search-results').append("<li data-theme='j'><img src='" + film.poster_path + "' alt='Poster' /><a href=''><h3 class='ui-li-heading'>" + film.title + "</h3><p class='ui-li-desc'><strong>" + film.tagline + "</strong></p><p class='ui-li-desc'>" + film.overview + "</p></a></li>");
            }
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, text){
            console.log(jqxhr);
        }
    });
```

`EXISTING CONTENT DIV THAT HOLDS THE <ul> ELEMENT:`

```
 <div id="content-add-title" data-role="content">
    <ul id='film-search-results' data-role='listview'></ul>
 </div><!-- end content-add-title -->
```

`AND THE FUNCTION THAT CALLS THE AJAX METHOD:`

```
    $('#add-add-title-btn').click(function() {
        if ($('#add-title-type-select').val() === "movie") {
            $('#right-panel3').panel("close");
            $('#film-search-results').html("");
            searchFilms($('#add-title-name-field').val());
            $('#add-title-page').trigger("create");
            $('#film-search-results').listview("refresh");
        }
    });
```

really not sure why it won't style properly any one have any ideas?

Comment: Are you appending items to page or panel?

Comment: to the `<ul>` element of the content div

Comment: @Joe Did calling the `.listview('refresh');` in the success of the ajax call solve this for you?

Comment: @ross it's not clear whether the items are being creating inside page or panel, because if created inside panel, `.trigger('pagecreate')` should be called.

Comment: @Omar Thanks, I updated my answer to support both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the listview in the success of your ajax call, not in your click event handler -

```
success: function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    for(var i = 0;  i < Object.size(json); i++){
        var film = json[i.toString()];
        $('#film-search-results').append("<li data-theme='j'><img src='" + film.poster_path + "' alt='Poster' /><a href=''><h3 class='ui-li-heading'>" + film.title + "</h3><p class='ui-li-desc'><strong>" + film.tagline + "</strong></p><p class='ui-li-desc'>" + film.overview + "</p></a></li>");
    }
    $('#add-title-page').trigger("pagecreate"); // <- trigger pagecreate here, shouldnt need listview refresh
},
```

I'm guessing that your ajax call is inside of the `searchFilms` function.  When you call `$('#film-search-results').listview("refresh");` and `$('#add-title-page').trigger("create");` immediately after your call to `searchFilms` your ajax call isn't complete yet and hasn't populated the listview with the JSON response.  This is why it is not working.

Comment: `.trigger('pagecreate')` and you don't need `listview('refresh')` in this case ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/16657895/1771795